# Преобразовать String в KeyKode C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли как нибудь преобразовать String в KeyCode?
Например, чтобы было так.

```
string stof = "J";
KeyCode kk = KeyCode.stof;
Debug.Log(kk.ToString());

Выводит J
```

Comment: а если перевести строковое значение в char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку `KeyCode` — [это `enum`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html), вам должно помочь `enum.Parse`. Но вам нужно «угадать» имя.

Получается вот что:

```
(KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), stof)
```

Это поддерживает только буквы.

Более строгий вариант такой (заодно поддерживает цифры):

```
char c = 'J'; // начинаем с символа, т. к. в строке может быть их много
string keyName;
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    keyName = c.ToString();
else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    keyName = "Alpha" + c;
else
    throw new ArgumentException("Don't know name for this key");

KeyCode kk = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), keyName);
```

(Проверить не могу, у меня нет Unity.)